# couldnt connect to DB through hibernate in eclipse

Tags: hibernate

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">*****</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<mapping resource="Product.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Product.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="str.Product" table="products">

    <id name="productId" column="pid"  />
    <property name="proName" column="pname" length="10"/>
    <property name="price"/>

    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Product.java

```
 package Str;

    public class Product{

        private int productId;
        private String proName;
        private double price;

        public void setProductId(int productId)
        {
            this.productId = productId;
        }
        public int getProductId()
        {
            return productId;
        }

        public void setProName(String proName)
        {
            this.proName = proName;
        }
        public String getProName()
        {
            return proName;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price)
        {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public double getPrice()
        {
            return price;
        }
    }
```

ClientProgram.java

```
package Str;

                import org.hibernate.*;
                import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

                public class ClientProgram { 

                    public static void main(String[] args)
                    {

                        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
                        cfg.configure(); 

                        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
                        Session session = factory.openSession();
                        Object o=session.load(Product.class,new Integer(101));
                        Product s=(Product)o;
                        // For loading Transaction scope is not necessary...
                        System.out.println("Loaded object product name is___"+s.getProName());

                        System.out.println("Object Loaded successfully.....!!");
                        session.close();
                        factory.close();
                    }}
```

Ouput

```
  NFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
            Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
                at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1402)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1424)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
                at Str.ClientProgram.main(ClientProgram.java:12)
```

please rectify this

This is the code and when i am trying to run this its showing the error as mentioned above so please help me in this thank u all

Comment: Have you mentioned you hibernate.cfg.xml file in application context?

Comment: Also where have you placed your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: hibernate.cfg.xml must be in the root of the classpath when the webapp is started.  If you are using maven to build the project, put hibernate.cfg.xml in the src/main/resources directory so that when you build the war package, it will be automatically be placed in /WEB-INF/classes.  If you are not using maven, put the file in your WEB-INF/classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `hibernate.cfg.xml` to the directory `src/main/resources`. That will fix the issue